# How to change the default position of the sidebar in discovery (search results) page in DSpace from right side to the left on its jspui version?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, dspace

I would like to change the default position of the sidebar in discovery (search results) page in `DSpace jspui` version from right side to the left without using `CSS` floats.

I wish to do that by configuring the default structure which is `<col-md-9>` and then `<col-md-3>` (which includes the sidebar) and reverse these two.

Answer (score 0):

[Column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the path leading to the file and lines which i'll be able to do that on the default installation of DSpace?